# What is the best version of MySQL to use with Rails 3?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

What is the best version of MySQL to use with Rails 3 as of today (28/4/11)?

At the moment I got Mysql 5.5.11 community server and I have had lots of problems with it. I want to install an older version of MySQL. Which one would you recommend?

Thanks in advance.

PS: The issues were with the mysql2 gem.

Comment: Can you specify what problems you faced with mysql2 gem? It's the default in Rails 3. mysql gem (default for Rails2.x) and mysql2 gem should both work with MySQL server.

Answer (score 2):

I would say 5.1 *only* because of problems I had trying to compile the driver with MySQL 5.5 on mac (which is of course a show stopper).

And I had no issues at all with MySQL 5.1.

Answer (score 2):

Even with the very public outage it recently suffered, we would recommend Amazon's RDS service. We find it has been very reliable and easy to administer.

Our RDS instance is currently running MySQL version 5.1.45.